# Explanation Need On On Liferay single-approver-definition.xml Workflow?

Tags: liferay

I want to achieve Multi Level Workflow in liferay for that i have an Idea how to Do write Xml File For that but i am need Some Explation On some Of The Tag Or On Some Code.

I Go Through With the Liferay Community there i got good explanation but i want to know in Depth Can Any One Explain?

Why We Are using below snippet

```
<metadata>
        <![CDATA[{"xy":[36,51]}]]>
</metadata>
```

Specially `"xy":[36,51]` why we are using that number what is the purpose For using that And Some Below Snippet Regarding That

```
<metadata>
        <![CDATA[{"transitions":{"resubmit":{"bendpoints":[[303,140]]}},"xy":[328,199]}]]>
</metadata>
```

,

and

```
<![CDATA[
            {"xy":[380,51]}
        ]]>
```

Any Help Will Help Me A lot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `<metadata>` elements inside of the workflow definition xml refere to visual aspects of the kaleo workflow designer. `xy` are coordinates used for rendering nodes and edges. They are not that import for your functional requirements. In fact, you can remove them all and Liferay will recreate them after pasting the definition to your kaleo designer.
Since you have not mentioned which Liferay Version, the following might help in 6.2 (and basically in DXP):

[Creating new Workflow-Definitions](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-new-workflow-definitions)